# Return multiple category value from XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

```
`<cassettes>
 <cassette>
    <cassetteId>A</cassetteId>
    <capacity>290</capacity>
    <denominations>
      <denomination>
        <value>1</value>
        <currency>US</currency>
        <notesAvailable>398</notesAvailable>
        <notesToDispense>24</notesToDispense>
        <notesDispensed>24</notesDispensed>
        <notesDeposited>0</notesDeposited>
        <notesSuggested>398</notesSuggested>
      </denomination>
    </denominations>
    <status>0</status>
    <position>0</position>
  </cassette>...`
```

Above is an excerpt from the xml column value. The node with the amount in question is "notesdispensesed".There are 12 cassetteId's A-K. Each cassette holds a denomination. For example: cassettes A & B contain 1s, Cassette C contain 5s, Casette D & E contain 10's etc...

The below select stmt returns the value 24 for cassetteId A. Im trying to avoid having to write this out twelve times for each cassette. Is there a way to return the dispensed amounts based on denomination value. Any solutions are greatly appreciated

```
Select column.value('(/cassettes/cassette/denominations/denomination/notesDispensed)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

Comment: *Full* sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like what you are looking for using sql:variable?

```
DECLARE @iterator = 1

SELECT 
    Child.value('(/cassettes/cassette/denominations/denomination/notesDispensed)[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
FROM
    XMLField.nodes("/cassettes/denomination[sql:variable("@iterator")]/ChildNode") AS N(Child)
```